# Making a vertical line

Tags: html, css

I want to do something like this..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaiHD.png)

I need to do this vertical line and the bottom border for every input. anyone has an idea?

Comment: did you try anything at all? please show us the code that you've done so far

Comment: no code no chocolate. we can help but no do your thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic structure you can use. Now it is up to you to integrate this with the elements of your website...

**However, please be aware that Stack Overflow is not an outsourcing website where you ask people to code for you. Try to find a solution yourself and come here if you need help.**

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#wrapper > div > div {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
}
    
#separator {
  height: 90px;
  border-left: solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div>
      <div>1: plcHolder</div>
      <div>3: plcHolder</div>
    </div>
    <div id="separator"></div>
    <div>
      <div>2: plcHolder</div>
      <div>4: plcHolder</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: now tha the job is done, .... `<ol>` could be used too https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRNNQE